# M.2 drive possibly corrupted after abrupt shutdown?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios

I built my computer in around July 2020, with a 512 GB M.2 SSD (specifically the Teamgroup MP34) and a 2 TB HDD. The mainboard is an ASUS ROG Strix B450-F. The power cable for my power supply seems to be finicky and goes out every so often if I slightly my computer, and this time it caused the machine to shut down.

However, when I booted it back up, it said "Reboot and Select proper Boot Device". I went into BIOS and it turns out it wasn't recognizing my SSD at all, and naturally my Windows installation was on my SSD. Since then, I have tried multiple things with no avail:

- messing with BIOS settings regarding compatibility, NVMe support, etc
- resetting BIOS settings
- putting the SSD in a different slot
- putting a clean Windows 10 ISO onto a USB and clicking repair options; also tried a new installation but it complained about missing drivers
- the NVME version of [the power cycle trick](https://dfarq.homeip.net/fix-dead-ssd/) in both slots

I've come to the conclusion that my SSD is no longer working at all and suspect that the sudden shut down may have corrupted my SSD in some way and made it unusable. Is this a possibility, and if so, what is my best plan of action? I don't have any other devices I can easily put the SSD in (to test or try to recover any data), and my laptop runs Manjaro Linux.

Comment: Depends on what caused the shutdown. Could be a faulty PSU, a power surge or the drive died and took the system down. I would get a new surge protector and a replacement SSD.

Comment: @spikey_richie seems reasonable, but if I go through with that is there any way I could recover my data from the old drive? I don't think it was the SSD's fault though, as I have had some similar shutdowns before, just without the drive dying.

Comment: Depends if the SSD is fried. Do you have another PC you could install it into? If you need to recover data, it may be a specialist job which is £££/$$$/€€€. This is why we make backups.

Comment: I don't, sadly, as I said in my post. I suppose I could try opening my laptop and putting it in there but I'm not too confident and am worried the adhesive on the rubber feet/screw covers will fall off (I've already opened it up once). Would buying an external enclosure work?